# Angular. Set attribute from view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have my own tag  on my page. This TAG I replace on INPUT.
And all INPUT have same value.
But user can change mode: INPUT may be READONLY, DISABLED and EDITABLE.

I did so: when I transformed TAG to INPUT, I add attributes readonly="readonly", disabled="disabled", editable="editable".
But I can change it dynamically from view.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z0XLoDe8Gjpibu0uXWG5?p=preview)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="myDirective" ng-controller="ctrl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>in</title>
<style>
    .red {background: red;}
    .green {background: green;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <tag value="it's value" state="readonly" css="red" ></tag><span>state="readonly"</span><br>
        <tag value="{{value}}" state="disabled" css="{{class}}" ></tag><span>state="disabled"</span><br>
        <tag value="{{value}}" state="editable" css="{{class}}" ></tag><br>
        <tag value="{{value}}" state="readonly" css="{{class}}" ></tag><span>state="readonly"</span><br>
        <tag value="{{value}}" state="readonly" css="green" ></tag><span>state="readonly"</span><br>
        <tag value="{{value}}" state="editable" css="{{class}}" ></tag><br>
        <tag value="{{value}}" state="editable" css="{{class}}" ></tag><br>
        <tag value="{{value}}" state="disabled" css="{{class}}" ></tag><span>state="disabled"</span><br>
        <tag value="{{value}}" state="editable" css="{{class}}" ></tag><br>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var myapp = angular.module("myDirective", []);

myapp.service('MyIdService', function(){
    var index = 1;

    this.getAndIncrement = function () {
        return index++;
    }
});
myapp.directive('tag', ['MyIdService', function(MyIdService){
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      scope: false,
      template: '<input type="text" id="id{{index}}" my-directive="curdata" placeholder="type smth" ></input>', 

      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.value = attrs.value;
            scope.index = MyIdService.getAndIncrement();

            element.attr('class', attrs.css); //replace attribute CSS to CLASS

            switch(attrs.state) {
                case "disabled":
                    element.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    break;
                case "readonly":
                    element.attr('readonly', 'readonly');
                    break;
                case "editable":

                    break;
                case "":

                    break;
                default:
                    // nothing
            } 
            //element.removeAttr('displaymode');    //doesn't work 
            //element.removeAttr('value');  //doesn't work 
     }
    };
}]);

myapp.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                myDirective: '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                // set initial value of textfield
                // element.val(scope.myDirective);
                // element.data('old-value', scope.myDirective);

                // detect changes and update INPUT
                scope.$watch('myDirective', function (val) {
                if (attrs.state == "editable") {
                element.val(scope.myDirective);
                }
                });

                // events
                element.bind('propertychange keyup cut paste blur input', function (blurEvent) {

                    if (attrs.state == "editable") {    
                        if (element.data('old-value') != element.val()) {
                            scope.$apply(function () {
                                scope.myDirective = element.val();
                                element.data('old-value', element.val());
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    });

/**
* when document opened, set current date
*/
function ctrl($scope, $filter ) {
    $scope.curdata= $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy');

  }

//  Get INPUT ID which you click
var target_id = '';
document.body.onclick = function(e) {
    var event = e || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement; 

    if (target.tagName != 'INPUT') return; //CAPITAL

    target_id = target.getAttribute('id');
    return false;
};
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I need watch changes of "STATE" attribute. If I changed value of STATE (ex. from 'readonly' to 'editable') in Mozilla Developer Tools, I haven't changes. Because my code doesn't see its.

Comment: If you have a question, you might try to clarify what is wrong and where you think the problem is. The first 2 paragraphs of your question make it sound like there is no issue at all.

Comment: I need watch changes of "STATE" attribute. If I changed value of STATE (ex. from 'readonly' to 'editable') in Mozilla Developer Tools, I haven't changes. Because my code doesn't see its.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your directive you can use `attrs.$observe()` to watch an attribute on the element that has your directive and execute code anytime it changes. Something like this:

```
    attrs.$observe('state', function(newAttributeValue) {
        // do something with newAttributeValue
    });
```

[Link to the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24compile.directive.Attributes).

**Edit**

Here is an example of how to use this with code:

HTML:

```
<tag value="it's value" state="myStateVariable" css="red" >
<button ng-click="changeState('editable')">Edit</button>
```

Javascript (in your AngularJS controller):

```
$scope.myStateVariable = "readonly";

$scope.changeState = function(newState) {
    $scope.myStateVariable = newState;
}
```

You seem to have a lot of these tags on the page, so obviously you don't want to make a variable for each one. You could use a plain old javascript object as a hash map, to keep track of all of states for each tag.

Comment: If I inserted alert('WORKs') in this function and changed value of STATE in Mozilla Dev Tools (ex. from 'readonly' to 'editable') I don't see message 'WORKs'.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily expect AngularJS to detect when you change the value with a "web inspector". You need to change the value of the attribute in code. To do this you put a variable(s) on the $scope and then wire up a button or something to a function that changes the variable.

Comment: I've added an example of how you should be changing the state. Changing the value w/Mozilla dev tools is not something I'd expect Angular to pick up on ;)

Comment: hm) I can't do it)) I added <button onclick="changeState1()">disabled</button>, added function, but it doesn't work [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AuFHQuQMAQq1QPui3ZaI?p=preview)